# Removing row in R based on a "typeof" list column

Tags: r, shapefile, typeof

I have looked through a few other solutions on how to remove a row based on a column value, but have not been able to do it for a "list" `typeof`. The following tibble is a shapefile built for classification training. To rasterize the shapefile, I need to remove rows that contain no geometry data. i.e. row 8. I can simply perform `df <- df$geometry[-8, ]`, however that would be inefficient for large data sets.

The geometry column also reads a bit different in the R dataframe (for some reason, this is what the `tibble` function outputted). The geometry column should read with a `c` (as in vector). i.e. `c(-123.1166, 44.67333)`. So the `EMPTY` actually reads `c(NaN, NaN)`.

I was thinking about turning the `typeof` "list" into a "string" and removing it like that??? Any suggestions?

```
# A tibble: 102 x 3
   Class Names2             geometry
   <dbl> <fct>           <POINT [°]>
 1     1 Hole   (-123.1166 44.67333)
 2     1 Hole   (-123.1166 44.67333)
 3     1 Hole   (-123.1166 44.67332)
 4     1 Hole    (-123.1167 44.6734)
 5     1 Hole    (-123.1167 44.6734)
 6     1 Hole   (-123.1166 44.67344)
 7     1 Hole   (-123.1165 44.67358)
 8     1 Hole                  EMPTY
 9     1 Hole   (-123.1167 44.67367)
10     1 Hole   (-123.1167 44.67367)
# ... with 92 more rows
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option with `map/filter`, where we loop over the `list` column 'geometry with `map`, check if not `all` the values are `NaN`, to return a logical vector in `filter` to remove those with all `NaN` values

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df1 %>%
      filter(map_lgl(geometry, ~ !all(is.nan(.x)))
```

---

If it is an `sf` object, an option is `st_is_empty`

```
library(sf)
df1 %>% 
    filter(!st_is_empty(geometry)]
```

Or it could be

```
df1 %>%
     st_is_empty(.) %>%
     `!` %>%
     magrittr::extract(df1, ., )
```

Comment: Your first and second answer gave me an error that reads: `Error in data.matrix(data): (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'`, but the third one worked!

Comment: @Zman3 ii tried to create a. reproducible example, but couldn't, so it was not tested properly